# MSCS file share majority: Why does it like a Windows-hosted share, but not a CIFS-based ZFS-hosted share?

Tags: solaris, network-share, zfs, windows-cluster

I'm looking to change the current file share used for the file share witness in an existing two-node MSCS SQL cluster. Currently, the share is hosted by a remote windows machine, and I want to move that so that it's hosted over CIFS by a Solaris NAS running ZFS.

I've configured the share on the NAS with guest write access and can access it from a client using `\\1.1.1.1\mscsquorum`. however, when I go through the Configure Cluster Quorum Wizard, it complains that `\\1.1.1.1\mscsquorum is not a valid file share path`. It will happily validate the old file share path at `\\2.2.2.2\Quorum`.

The only two differences that I can see are that the old file share is hosted on a Windows 2003 machine, and that box is a member of the same domain that is used for the cluster. The Solaris box on the other hand is not in any domain.

My suspicion is that the cluster wizard is trying to access the share with a domain account and check certain permissions, and it's failing because I've effectively allowed global guest access to the share. Is there any way this can be made to work, or must a file share witness always be hosted by a Windows machine on the same domain as the cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it make sense to export iSCSI from your ZFS NAS? I've tried to avoid using CIFS directly on the NAS for this reason. Also, have you considered just joining your Solaris system to the domain?

Comment: I'd tried using an iSCSI LUN configured with a node and disk majority, but encountered random issues with the disk suddenly being dropped by the cluster members (they're VMs running on top of vSphere 5.0). This happened regardless of whether I connected to the LUN from within vSphere and exposed it to the guests, or whether I connected directly using the MS iSCSI initiator. I might try this option again to see if I can replicate it.